# Target different element inside same section in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page for a members display and I use loop inside foreach to input members. each individual member has following html markup

**loop starts here**

```
<div class="member">
<div class="row wrapper">
<div class="image col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-12">
<a href="#" class="image-wrapper background-image">
<img src="abc.jpg" alt="member-profile" class="img img-responsive bm-profile-img" >
</a>                                        
</div>
<div class="cont col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9 col-xs-12">
<div class="row">
<h3>
<a class="title">Title</a>
</h3>
</div>
<div class="row">
<h4 class="summary">
<a href="#">Summary</a>
</h4>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="description">
<p>Description</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="detail read-more" id="bd-read-more">See All</div >
</div>
</div>                                                              
</div>                              
</div>
```

**loop ends here**

div description is hidden by default. When someone clicks on See All, it should be shown. I can achieve it by using simple jQuery, like this

```
$("#bd-read-more").click(function(){
$(".description").slideToggle('slow', 'swing');
});
```

My problem is, since I have multiple `.description` divs (one for each member), the all `.description` divs responds to one See All button click.

How can I make only `.description` div from clicked See All button section respond?

Comment: Have you got multiple buttons with the same id? If so, that's a no-no - make it a class instead. Then you can find the right `.description` div by targeting it inside your `click` handler by something like `$(this).siblings(".description")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```
$(".read-more").click(function() { // Note I've changed from ID to class, since ID shall always be unique
  $(this).closest(".wrapper").find(".description").slideToggle('slow', 'swing');
});
```

`.closest('.wrapper')` is going "up" in your html tree and looking for the first element with the class `wrapper`.

`.find('.description')` is looking "down" in your html and finding all elements with the class `description`

This will look for the closest element with the class `wrapper` and then find the `description` element and work the magic on it.

**Demo**

```js
$(".read-more").click(function() {
  $(this).closest(".wrapper").find(".description").slideToggle('slow', 'swing');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="member">
  <div class="row wrapper">
    <div class="image col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-12">
      <a href="#" class="image-wrapper background-image">
        <img src="abc.jpg" alt="member-profile" class="img img-responsive bm-profile-img">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="cont col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9 col-xs-12">
      <div class="row">
        <h3>
          <a class="title">Title</a>
        </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <h4 class="summary">
          <a href="#">Summary</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="description">
          <p>Description</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="detail read-more" id="bd-read-more">See All</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. thank you very much. can you help me understand what you did here? Im new to jquery

Comment: No problem @jowoke Happy to help, I've updated the answer